# Filtering accelerometer data using SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to filter a large amount of accelerometer data using pandas, NumPy, and SciPy. I wanted to customize my frequency response, so I found that firwin2 would be a good option for filtering. Here is my code for filtering a data stream:

```
def actigraph_filter(series):
    SF=25
    Nyq=SF/2
    points = np.arange(0,13,1)
    gain = [0, .05, .4, .95, 1, .9, .85, .7, .6, .45, .35, .25, 0]
    b = signal.firwin2(numtaps=170, freq=points, gain=gain, nyq=Nyq)
    return signal.filtfilt(b, [1.0], series)
```

My data is recorded at 25 Hz, and as you can see, I sketched out a (very) rough frequency response, just to try to get things working. 
This function runs in a pipeline to read, filter, and eventually produce counts for my data, but when I run my code on a piece of data I get this error:

```
    File "/Users/wharper/Accelerometry-Data-Processing/geneactiv_counts.py", line 45, in actigraph_filter
    return signal.filtfilt(b, [1.0], series)
  File "/Users/wharper/accelerometry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py", line 3087, in filtfilt
    ntaps=max(len(a), len(b)))
  File "/Users/wharper/accelerometry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py", line 3145, in _validate_pad
    ext = odd_ext(x, edge, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/wharper/accelerometry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/_arraytools.py", line 102, in odd_ext
    ext = np.concatenate((2 * left_end - left_ext,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

and I'm not so sure how to proceed.
Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  In Python 2, `Nyq` will have the value 12 (an integer), not 12.5.

Comment: The error is occurring in `signal.filtfilt(b, [1.0], series)`.  I suspect `series` is not an array of numbers.  It would help if you created a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Warren, the problem was that I was splitting my DataFrame by column, then inputing "column.values" into the filtering function. But that meant that the index was also going through, and that was causing the error.